# How to test that an inner function has been called from an imported function? (with Jest.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm having issues with Jest testing that a closure (an inner function) has been called after calling the outer function. I've tried using the `spyOn` with no positive result. This seems to be a relatively simple problem, to which I haven't found any results from googling.

```
// helper.js
export const bar = () => {}
export const foo = () => {
  bar(); //How do I test that this has been called?
}


//helper.test.js
import * as H from 'helper';

const barSpy = jest.spyOn(H, 'bar');
H.foo();

expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Jest throws error "Expected mock function to have been called."
```

Comment: can you log `barSpy` to see the state? If consoles are swallowed by jest try, `process.nextTick(() => console.log(barSpy))` will log it at end of test but shouldn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: Pretty sure that an import object is not a normal object. Checking...

Comment: ...yup. It's a special object. [More details](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports). Not exactly sure how jest's `spyOn` is implemented but am guessing it involves overwriting the original property/method which you can't do with Module objects.

Comment: One last thing, this whole question is perhaps misguided, why are you testing an implementation detail of `foo` by seeing whether or not it calls `bar`? That's a testing code-smell usually.

Comment: @JaredSmith there's conditional logic within foo that tests other function calls. I've decided to leave out the extraneous parts to leave the question succinct.

Comment: @Gunther that doesn't really remove my objection. What functions `foo` calls is still an implementation detail, even if you are calling those functions purely for their side effects. If you want to test side effects, test *that* they happened, not *how* they happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once, and found this article which is very well explained: https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/

From the article:

> Stubbing a function in Javascript requires the function to be bound to a context, any context, that is in scope for both the test code and the code being tested. In a sane world this context is provided by the module. For example, in ES5 Node.js:
>
> `exports.fn = function () {}`
>
> The thing to avoid doing in ES5 is the following, overriding module.exports with a function. All too many people do this and it is inconsiderate, as any module using that code must then take extra steps to be usefully unit tested:
>
> `module.exports = function () {}`

So the last exported function can't be stubbed since it's not bound to any context, theres a workaraound for that, bounding the function to the exports object of the module you are testing and calling it as `exports.importedFunction`, like so:

```
var example = require('./example');

// Exported for test purposes. If we don't do this, then
// example is encapsulated here and cannot be stubbed.
exports.example = example;

// Usage.
exports.invokeExample = function () {
   return exports.example();
};
```

Then you'll be able to spy on it, but you had to write that extra code, which is kinda ugly and not very useful neither clear.

> In ES6 using "import { x } from 'y'" is analogous to overwriting module.exports with a function in ES5. The result is that an imported function is encapsulated in the module and cannot be stubbed in unit tests without writing more boilerplate code that would otherwise have been the case.

This also happens for your case: `import * as H from 'helper'`

Comment: I think that article kinda misses the point. ES 6 Module objects are static and immutable because that has some nice properties: place nice with tools (e.g. bundlers, code-analyzers, dead code removers), circular dependencies are easier, the loader can be simpler, performance is better etc. You can make the argument that it isn't very "JavaScript-y" to do it that way (and I would) but the article seems to imply that there isn't any reason they did it that way other than to annoy developers. I heard a whole lot of "isn't the way I'm used to so it's wrong".