# How to set correct namespace in jest for a module attached to html in browser for testing a function's call to another function in that module?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

The question is formulated this way as I'm able to step into tested code in IDE and the actual code runs as expected, but the test fails.

There's a javascript file attached to testing HTML with `<script src="../example.js"></script>` and its content looks like:

```
function myFunc(myId) {
  console.log(myId);
}

function someOtherFunc(arg) {
  if (arg == 0)
    myFunc("#id_0");
  else
    myFunc("#id_1");
}

/*
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* SECTION: exports needed by jest testing framework
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*/
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = {
    myFunc,
    someOtherFunc,
  };
}
```

And the following is a simplified content of testing module `example.test.js` with one of (many) unsuccessful ways to test that call:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const html = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './example.html'), 'utf8');
const jquery = require('../../static/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js');

window.$ = jquery;
window.jQuery = jquery;

const mockSend = jest.fn();
global.WebSocket = jest.fn();
global.WebSocket.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    send: mockSend,
  };
});

const example = require('../example.js');

jest
  .dontMock('fs');

beforeEach(() => {
  document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});

describe('someOtherFunc function', function () {
  it('calls myFunc', function () {
    const spyFunc = jest.spyOn(example, "myFunc");
    const result = example.someOtherFunc(0);
    expect(spyFunc).toHaveBeenCalledWith("#id_0")
  });
});
```

I pasted this `mockSend` part here as I've managed to test that successfully with `expect(mockSend).toHaveBeenCalledWith("...");`. That `send` method is also inside another function and I test a calling function in jest module.

However, I can't find a way to make this 'calls myFunc' test to pass.

Comment: for it to work you have to write extra code you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756241/how-to-test-that-an-inner-function-has-been-called-from-an-imported-function-w) for more details.

Comment: @Chandan may you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stubbing a function in Javascript requires the function to be bound to a context, any context, that is in scope for both the test code and the code being tested. In a sane world this context is provided by the module. For example, in ES5 Node.js:
>
> exports.fn = function () {}
>
> The thing to avoid doing in ES5 is the following, overriding module.exports with a function. All too many people do this and it is inconsiderate, as any module using that code must then take extra steps to be usefully unit tested:
>
> module.exports = function () {}

As you can read from description it does not work because `myFunc` is bound to `example.js` file context.

It would have worked if:

- Modules import to `example.js`, like `path` module import
- Callbacks that can be pass into function when calling them from test

**Note:** For more details you can go [here](https://www.exratione.com/2015/12/es6-use-of-import-property-from-module-is-not-a-great-plan/)

According to description solution would be something like this:

---

#### Solution 1

myFunc.js

```js
function myFunc(myId) {
  console.log(myId);
}

if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = myFunc;
}
```

example.js

```js
var myFunc = require('./myFunc'); // This needs to be imported using script tag for browser

function someOtherFunc(arg) {
  console.log('inside', myFunc);
  if (arg == 0)
    myFunc("#id_0");
  else
    myFunc("#id_1");
}

if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = {
    someOtherFunc
  };
}
```

example.test.js

```js
const example = require('../example.js');
const myFunc = require('../myFunc.js');

jest.mock('../myFunc.js');

afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});

describe('someOtherFunc function', function () {
  it('calls myFunc', function () {
    const result = example.someOtherFunc(0);
    expect(myFunc).toHaveBeenCalledWith("#id_0")
  });
});
```

---

#### Solution 2

example.js

```
function myFunc(myId) {
  console.log(myId);
}

function someOtherFunc(arg) {
  if (arg == 0)
    my_functions.myFunc("#id_0");
  else
    my_functions.myFunc("#id_1");
}

const my_functions = {
  myFunc,
  someOtherFunc,
};

/*
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* SECTION: exports needed by jest testing framework
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*/
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = my_functions;
}
```

example.test.js

```
const example = require('../example');

afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
});

describe('someOtherFunc function', function () {
  it('calls myFunc', function () {
    const spyFunc = jest.spyOn(example, "myFunc");
    const result = example.someOtherFunc(0);
    expect(spyFunc).toHaveBeenCalledWith("#id_0")
  });
});
```

---

#### Setup

package.json

```
{
  "name": "65287977",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
  },
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          esmodules: true
        }
      }
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't grasp this. I can comprehend that this solves call to `jest.spyOn(example, "someOtherFunc")`, but how can I use this "middleware" invokeExample for catching calls to `jest.spyOn(example, "myFunc")`? Also, I can't understand that "like path module import" part.

Comment: @ipaleka i have updated my answer with example for changes needed in code for reference

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll accept this answer just because of your effort, but still can't find a way to test a call to a function from another function in the same module.

Comment: @ipaleka i have added another solution by which you can test a call to a function from another function in the same module.

Comment: Well done, thank you very much! It's all about planned testing from the start and this solution proves that.